# RDD with empty string make 0.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD, called doctor, like:

```
age,part,day,val
9,elbow,Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 3399,1.0
9,elbow,Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 3399,
9,neck,Mon Aug 18 00:00:00 EDT 3499,1.0
```

There is an empty space in some of the rows at the val column.
Is there a way to keep this RDD but replace all the empty strings with a 0.0?

I tried a map with a conditional `.isEmpty()` but a double can't use `isEmpty()`.
I also tried a conditional in a map where `(if doctor.val == '') 0.0 else doctor.val`, but that does not work either

Answer (score 1):

I think `spark-csv` would help, but here is the pure Scala approach.

When you said "empty space", I assumed you literally meant there was some whitespace there, and the line didn't just end with a comma.

```
case class Doctor(age:Int, part:String,day:String,value:Double)

val line = "9,elbow,Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 3399, "
val data = line.split(",").map(_.trim).map {
    case "" => "0.0"
    case (x:String) => x 
}
val doc = Doctor(data(0).toInt, data(1), data(2), data(3).toDouble)
```

Output

```
data: Array[String] = Array(9, elbow, Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 3399, 0.0)
doc: Doctor(9,elbow,Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 EDT 3399,0.0)
```

---

As far as Spark is concerned... This makes an `RDD[Doctor]`

```
case class Doctor(age:Int, part:String,day:String,value:Double)

sc.textFile(fileName).map { line =>
    val data = line.split(",").map(_.trim).map {
        case "" => "0.0"
        case (x:String) => x 
    }
    Doctor(data(0).toInt, data(1), data(2), data(3).toDouble)
}
```

Comment: Can you do this on an RDD?

Comment: Sure. Something like `sc.textFile("file.txt").map { line => ... }`?

Comment: that's what I've been trying but I can't preserve all elements and remove the empty string because it is a double and we can't do double.isEmpty()

Comment: An empty string isn't a double... This code goes before you convert that column to a double